# Content width is increasing for every new change

Tags: javafx-8

I have a project where one of it's windows is a ScrollPane that has a GridPane as a content. when I click on a new node, or I start typing on the text fields. the width of a GridPane's column increases unintentionally. can anyone explain why would that be happening.
I tried to get rid of ScrollPane on the window but it's still going on. My window's width is bind to the window's width also.

Comment: The best way to get help is to provide code that exhibits the symptoms of the issue. It's called a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can boil it down to a minimal code example, you'll get answers, guaranteed. :)

Comment: Impossible to tell the exact issue. Especially since binding is involved in a way that's not explained well enough for me to understand the exact details... Could be the preferred width changing or could be the binding done incorrectly... Imho bindings are a last resort. There are almost always alternatives to this using the proper layouts or applying the right properties to the layouts being used...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your support on this problem. Turns out the issue was something completely unrelated to anything I wrote down. The problem was on a TableView I set to increase its columns' width based on the content.

```
ingredientTable = new TableView<Ingredient>();
ingAmount = new TableColumn<Ingredient, Integer>("amount");
ingUnit = new TableColumn<Ingredient, String>("unit");
ingName = new TableColumn<Ingredient, String>("item");
ingredientTable.getColumns().addAll(ingAmount, ingUnit, ingName);

ingAmount.prefWidthProperty().bind(ingredientTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.1));
ingUnit.prefWidthProperty().bind(ingredientTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.2));
ingName.prefWidthProperty().bind(ingredientTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.70));
```

For some reason, whenever I changed content anywhere (clicked on a new node or type on TextField) the tableview would increase it's width. I just reduced the multiply parameter of one of the TableColumn to `0.01` and that seemed to solve the problem.

I'm sorry for my lack of information and expect more details in future posts